# @POST in Jersey Viewable

Tags: jersey

Any example on Jersey Viewable using @POST methods ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@POST
@Path("register")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response register(RegisterRequest request) throws Exception {
    HashMap<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("request", request);
    return Response.ok(new Viewable("/register", model)).build();
}
```